# How to compile the linux kernel with an obsolete option?

Tags: linux, kernel, xilinx, obsolete

OK, so I have this embedded kernel whose network card used to work fine with the LLTEMAC option. The new one with LL_TEMAC doesn't. I still see the code with LLTEMAC in the source, but not in the available option in the .config file:

```
$ ack-grep LLTEMAC
drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_lltemac/Makefile:10:obj-$(CONFIG_XILINX_LLTEMAC) := xilinx_temac.o
drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_lltemac/xlltemac_main.c:2: * Xilinx Ethernet: Linux driver for the XPS_LLTEMAC core.
drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_lltemac/xlltemac_main.c:452:#ifdef CONFIG_XILINX_LLTEMAC_MARVELL_88E1111_RGMII
...
include/linux/xilinx_devices.h:83:/* LLTEMAC platform data */
```

Is there a way to compile the kernel with this removed option ?
Simply adding `CONFIG_XILINX_LLTEMAC=y CONFIG_XILINX_LLTEMAC_MARVELL_88E1111_GMII=y` to the .config file does not do anything as the dislaimer states: `# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just update this individual driver to understand the new configuration option?

Comment: It's being phased out so the code is still there but the options to activate it are gone, as well as who knows what else...